# "On the test" or "in the test"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, word-difference, transatlantic-differences

I know we should say "on the test" meaning performance wise, but does using "in the test" go as well or has another meaning?

Do we say:

> So the kids are able to do their best **on** the test.

or

> So the kids are able to do their best **in** the test.

Answer (score 5):

In the US it's always **on** the test.  "I hope you do well on the test" is correct.

"Try to stay relaxed in the test" is not anything that I've heard.  The more common preposition is "*during* the test" -- although if someone said "in the test" I'd know what they meant.

Answer (score 1):

It's always "in the test", at least in the UK. Something may be "on-test", but when a person is doing a test, he (or she) is definitely "in" it (and sometimes feels it).

Answer (score 0):

In AmE:

Try to stay relaxed and focused in the test.  (during it)

How well did you do on the test?

Comment: I would just use "during" in the first sentence. Also you did not address the choice in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20test%2C%20on%20the%20test&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20test%3B%2Cc0) as quick and dirty reference, *in the test* is the normal, standard usage in global English.

Whether it is an AmE v BrE thing is less clear. Switching to [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20test%2Con%20the%20test&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20test%3B%2Cc0) shows that *in the test* is slightly more popular in the USA, though in 1960 it was a lot more standard. In [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20test%2Con%20the%20test&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20test%3B%2Cc0) *in the test* is definitely standard usage.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression: 'the kids did well in the test,' sounds more as a natural collocation to me. Here in Nigeria we tend to speak more of British English. But I also know that the Americans usually say ' on test.' And would say 'in test' if someone is on a test(writing a test).